# Unity OnMouseOver is offset to where my mouse actually is

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity and I want to detect when the mouse is over a square on a 2D UI. I want to use OnMouseEnter and OnMouseExit as triggers (or any other way if this is the wrong method) to make the square change color when mouse hovers over it.

**Problem**

The detection seems to be working fine, but it is offset to where my mouse is. The square changes color a good bit before the mouse actually enters. In the picture below the red dot is where the mouse was when the top green square changed from grey to green.

[image]

**What I've tried**

Right now I just have a simple Monobehaviour script which looks something like this:

```
public class Node : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{

    [HideInInspector] private Color32 canPlaceColor = new Color32(159, 255, 159, 255);
    
    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = canPlaceColor;
    }
}
```

I tried changing my Canvas scaling from Scale with screen size to Constant pixel but there is still an offset. Also tried changing camera to orthogonally which also did nothing.

**Question**

What is going on, why is there an offset to when OnMouseEnter detects the mouse over? Is there a better method of doing this?

Comment: Are you sure that your UI elements/objects do not have anything that makes them actually bigger as their visual parts? E.g. any `Image` or `Text` component that has `Raycast Target` enabled or `Collider` that is bigger then the actual displayed content?

Comment: Yes all it has is an image (same size as object) and the collider is the same.

Comment: Instead of `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseExit` methods, try using `OnPointerEnter` and `OnPointerExit` methods from `IPointerEnterHandler` and `IPointerExitHandler` interfaces respectively